# protecting an API written in asp.net 5 / web api 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, identityserver4

All the samples explain how to protect an API written in asp.net core.

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
               .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
               {
                   options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                   options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                   options.ApiName = "api1";
               });
```

Is it possible to protect APIs written in asp.net 5 / web api2 with full .net framework using Identity Server 4. How?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

Use `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` from assembly `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` to configure openid connect in your startup configuration code:

For example

```
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions() {
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
                ClientId = "yourclientid",
                RedirectUri = "http://yourredirecturi",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
        });
```